# Understading cppcheck warning and errors?

Tags: compilation, kernel, cppcheck

I was trying to understanding check list of warning/error thrown by cppcheck from https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/wiki/ListOfChecks/

I come across following warning in auto section :-

- suspicious assignment of pointer argument.
- useless assignment of function argument.

what is meaning of these , Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The link given in the question is broken. Better to provide log in the question post itself. For make log less, choose only some reports and remove messages which doesn't related to them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev fixed link.